# Gitlab-PythonApi Merge request

Tags: python, api, gitlab, merge-request

How to check the merge request status in GitLab using a python API call, I want to check the status of approval before merging, based on the status of approval have to do some checks, once checks are approved  then merge will takes place

```
import gitlab
import os
import json
Gitlab_repo = "https://gitlab.devtools.xxxx.com/"
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(Gitlab_repo, private_token='xxxx')
project = gl.projects.get(projectid)
merge_request = project.mergerequests.get(merge_request number)
print(merge_request)
```

Output:

```
{
   "source_branch":"",
   "id":,
   "references":{
      "full":"",
      "relative":"",
      "short":""
   },
   "project_id":,
   "time_stats":{
      "time_estimate":0,
      "human_total_time_spent":"None",
      "total_time_spent":0,
      "human_time_estimate":"None"
   },
   "description":"",
   "merge_when_pipeline_succeeds":,
   "work_in_progress":,
   "changes_count":"",
   "reference":"",
   "first_deployed_to_production_at":"None",
   "source_project_id":,
   "should_remove_source_branch":"None",
   "milestone":"None",
   "updated_at":"",
   "user_notes_count":0,
   "latest_build_finished_at":"None",
   "head_pipeline":"None",
   "subscribed":true,
   "web_url":"",
   "state":"opened",
   "created_at":"",
   "approvals_before_merge":"None",
   "user":{
      "can_merge":true
   },
   "iid":,
   "assignee":{
      "avatar_url":"None",
      "web_url":"",
      "id":,
      "username":"",
      "state":"",
      "name":""
   },
   "author":{
      "avatar_url":"None",
      "web_url":"",
      "id":,
      "username":"",
      "state":"active",
      "name":""
   },
   "target_project_id":,
   "merge_error":"None",
   "task_completion_status":{
      "count":0,
      "completed_count":0
   },
   "target_branch":"master",
   "squash":false,
   "assignees":[
      {
         "avatar_url":"None",
         "web_url":"",
         "id":,
         "username":"",
         "state":"active",
         "name":""
      }
   ],
   "merged_at":"None",
   "has_conflicts":false,
   "force_remove_source_branch":true,
   "merge_status":"can_be_merged",
   "labels":[
      
   ],
   "pipeline":"None",
   "title":"",
   "merged_by":"None",
   "closed_by":"None",
   "sha":"",
   "closed_at":"None",
   "diff_refs":{
      "start_sha":"",
      "head_sha":"",
      "base_sha":""
   },
   "squash_commit_sha":"None",
   "latest_build_started_at":"None",
   "downvotes":0,
   "upvotes":0,
   "discussion_locked":"None",
   "merge_commit_sha":"None",
   "blocking_discussions_resolved":true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After creation you can get parameters of merge request:

```py
# create MR
mr = project.mergerequests.create({'source_branch': 'cool_feature',
                                   'target_branch': 'master',
                                   'title': 'merge cool feature',
                                   'labels': ['label1', 'label2']})
```

get URL

```py
print(getattr(mr,'web_url'))
```

or

```py
print(getattr(mr,'merge_error'))
```

or set it as variable to next code('has_conflicts' - True or False, in this example):

```py
merge_has_no_conflicts = getattr(mr,'has_conflicts')
if merge_has_no_conflicts:
   do_smthg
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the python Gitlab API library, but Merge Request Approvals can be retrieved from a separate API. They're not in the Merge Requests API but rather the Merge Request Approvals API, which is a paid feature. You must be at least a Premium customer to use the API.

With the Merge Request Approvals API you can approve a MR, unapprove, or get the approval status of a MR. To get the status, use the following endpoint:

`GET /projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/approval_state`

The results will look like:

```json
{
  "approval_rules_overwritten": true,
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Ruby",
      "rule_type": "regular",
      "eligible_approvers": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "John Doe",
          "username": "jdoe",
          "state": "active",
          "avatar_url": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0?s=80&d=identicon",
          "web_url": "http://localhost/jdoe"
        }
      ],
      "approvals_required": 2,
      "users": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "John Doe",
          "username": "jdoe",
          "state": "active",
          "avatar_url": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0?s=80&d=identicon",
          "web_url": "http://localhost/jdoe"
        }
      ],
      "groups": [],
      "contains_hidden_groups": false,
      "approved_by": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "John Doe",
          "username": "jdoe",
          "state": "active",
          "avatar_url": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0?s=80&d=identicon",
          "web_url": "http://localhost/jdoe"
        }
      ],
      "source_rule": null,
      "approved": true,
      "overridden": false
    }
  ]
}
```

This will include the applicable rules for MR approval, who has already approved the MR if available, and a simple boolean indicating if the MR is approved or not.

You can read more about the Merge Request Approvals API and its other operations in [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_request_approvals.html#get-the-approval-state-of-merge-requests).